# Azure Search Indexer Cache can't write to Storage Account with Firewall Rule

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I've been going back and forth with that issue, so I really hope somebody can help me here.

I've got an Azure AI Search Instance in Western Europe and want to use the Enrichment Cache Feature of the Indexer.

The Storage Account (also in Western Europe) that I use has a restricted network policy. I added the Search as a *trusted service* at the storage account networking policy. (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-howto-access-trusted-service-exception#check-permissions)).

The connection uses system-managed identities and the Search has Data Storage Contributor Access to this storage account.

The setup works for indexing data. However, for Caching and Knowledge Store, I get the following error:

```
Status: Failed
Error message: Credentials provided in the connection string are invalid or have expired. For more information on troubleshooting connection issues to Azure Storage accounts, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2049388
```

Yes, I made sure the connection string that is being used is in the managed identity format (`ResourceId=/...`). When I set the network's networking to "Allow all networks" I can connect successfully, so RBAC works fine.

I've also tried to add the search as Resource Instance in the storage networking policy. Same error...

Any tips? How do others implement this common scenario, when the Azure Search should have a public ip but the storage should be protected?

Every answer is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Per the [documentation you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-howto-access-trusted-service-exception#prerequisites), "Trusted Service" connections are unfortunately not supported for Azure Tables. The Azure Search Indexer Enrichment Cache feature uses both blobs and tables for record keeping.

> In Azure AI Search, a trusted service connection is limited to blobs and ADLS Gen2 on Azure Storage. It's unsupported for indexer connections to Azure Table Storage and Azure File Storage.

Comment: Thanks for this! At least, I now understand why it doesn't work. Do you have an idea how to make it work? As both services are in the same location, IP-rules also don't apply.

The "resource instance rule" also had no effect. Looks like there is no 'easy' solution for this...